# Sort array not working

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort array alphabetically using php sort function.

```
Array ( [0] => Open Sans [1] => Wellfleet [2] => Rambla [3] => Dosis [4] => Noto Sans [5] => Domine [6] => Signika Negative [7] => Arvo [8] => Neuton [9] => Rufina [10] => Tinos [11] => Podkova [12] => Magra [13] => Bitter [14] => Anton [15] => Libre Baskerville [16] => Tienne [17] => Roboto [18] => Ruda [19] => Merriweather [20] => Amaranth [21] => Playfair Display SC [22] => Cinzel Decorative [23] => Nobile [24] => Volkhov [25] => Nunito [26] => Merriweather Sans [27] => Stardos Stencil [28] => Bree Serif )
```

I have tried this one

```
$heading_fonts = sort($heading_fonts);
```

Eventually I am combining array to get same key and value.

```
$heading_fonts = array_combine($heading_fonts, $heading_fonts);
```

But giving me an error.

```
Warning: array_combine() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in...
```

Any idea how can I sort an array to work?

Comment: `array_combine($heading_fonts, $heading_fonts);` This is combining an array with itself. What are you actually trying to do in this line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`sort`](http://php.net/sort) function will sort your array in place and return a boolean value indicating its success. You should not assign its return value to the array. Use just:

```
sort($heading_fonts);
```

Comment: Wonderful.. I didn't know that and was trying to return value with variable. Just wonder how it is possible passing through without returning the value?

Comment: It changes the given array. It doesn't create a new one. Btw, shouldn't an array be called with [] at the end? Or am I confusing this with C# et cetera?

Comment: @WesleyDeKeirsmaeker in PHP this is not needed

Comment: @pixelngrain: It's because the array is passed as reference. http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: Yeah, in the function documentation (http://php.net/sort) you can see that the first parameter is passed as reference (`&$array`)

Answer (score 2):

Learn to use the [documentation](http://php.net/sort):

```
bool sort ( array &$array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR ] )
```

Notice the ampersand (`&`) in-front of the `$array` parameter. The ampersand is a [*reference operator*](http://php.net/references).

It is also important to always take note of a function's return value. Many questions here on SO can be solved simply by finding out what a function actually does, and what it returns.

```
Return Values
    Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.
```

So, this is how you sort an array:

```
$someArray = array(8,2,6,1,0);
sort($someArray);
// $someArray is now sorted
```

If you assign the return value to `$someArray`, like this:

```
$someArray = array(8,2,6,1,0);
$someArray = sort($someArray);
```

...then `$someArray` is overwritten by the sort() function's return value (which would be `TRUE` in this case).

The "Examples" section of the documentation is also very instructive.

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving me great knowledge. It is sometime difficult what they have described in documentation. Thanks again.